# Разбить строку на 80 символов с сохранением пунктуации и символов переноса

Tags: строки

Как мне разбить строку, в которой присутствуют знаки препинания и символы переноса, с сохранением этих символов?

Есть текст, его надо разбить и записать в файл. Разбитые строки должны быть не более 80 символов (включая знаки препинания), а так же сохранены переносы абзацев. Этакий "перенос по словам" из Word'a.

PS Дополнительные библиотеки использовать нельзя.

Comment: И что у вас не получилось?

Comment: Все зависит от языка программирования, в каждом языке есть свои средства для этого.

Comment: язык Python 3. Значит у меня строка(литературный текст) более 6000 символов, в ней есть символы '\n', которые обозначают новые абзацы, через pprint все возвращается великолепно, так скажем в читабельном виде. Мне же необходимо эту строку записать в txt файлик, но в отформатированном виде , где максимальная ширина строки будет 80 символов и перенос слов будут, аля "перенос по словам" из Word'а. Так же необходимо сохранить абзацы.

Comment: пытаюсь написать цикл, который считает количество символов и каждые 80й символ вставляет "\n"

Comment: Снимите холд) вопрос сейчас понятен.

Comment: Берешь великолепный pprint и указываешь stream=. Стрим создается через strinio или из файла https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html